# lpr not printing

Tags: lubuntu, printing

I have an HP inkjet printer connected to an lubuntu laptop with a USB cable, installed under CUPS as "inkjet".  I can print with AbiWord OK, and a printer test page prints OK from the printer properties dialog, but if I try to print from the command line with "lpr -Pinkjet", nothing happens.  I don't get any error message, and the inkjet print queue shows as empty.  lpstat shows the print queue as empty.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.  The printer driver is hp-envy_4510_series-hpijs.ppd.

Any ideas?

*** Edit 11 Dec 2018 ***

I see some error messages in the CUPS error log:

```
E [11/Dec/2018:09:08:43 -0500] Unknown directive JobPrivateAccess on line 85 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [11/Dec/2018:09:08:43 -0500] Unknown directive JobPrivateValues on line 86 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [11/Dec/2018:09:08:43 -0500] Unknown directive SubscriptionPrivateAccess on line 87 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
E [11/Dec/2018:09:08:43 -0500] Unknown directive SubscriptionPrivateValues on line 88 of /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
W [11/Dec/2018:09:08:48 -0500] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
W [11/Dec/2018:09:08:48 -0500] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
W [11/Dec/2018:09:08:48 -0500] CreateDevice failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
```

I am too ignorant of CUPS to know what to do about them or to judge their severity, so I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Please try the command with a space between the `P` and the `inkjet` as in `lpr -P inkjet`

Comment: @CharlesGreen No change with "lpr -P inkjet".  Still not printing.

Comment: What does [`lpstat -p -d`](https://superuser.com/a/177461/14566) return?

Comment: @unutbu lpstat -p -d prints "printer inkjet is enabled.  enabled since ...", "system default designation: inkjet"

Comment: According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/584136/8005) on lubuntu you need to install the `cups-bsd` package (NOT the `lpr` package) to have lpr use CUPS.

Comment: I'm glad this solved the problem for you! When two questions have the same answer, it is generally [StackExchange etiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/137631) to upvote the answer that solved your problem and to vote to close one as a duplicate of the other. This links the the two questions together (under the "Linked" section of each page) and helps others (who may come across a duplicate  first) find the answer.

Comment: @unutbu OK, but I can't vote to close, I guess I don't have enough rep.  If you would like to vote to close, please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by installing the cups-bsd package, as recommended in [lp works but lpr does not](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584047/lp-works-but-lpr-does-not/584136#584136).  (If I had realized that lp was working, I might have found this answer sooner.)

I realize that it would be better to close this question and mark it as a duplicate, as recommended by unutbu, but I don't have enough rep to vote to close, so I am posting this answer in an attempt to achieve some kind of closure.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux, so I list a lot of basics you may be aware of.
I was using Bottle 43.2 ,USB cabled connecting to a Canon printer. All I could get at first, was worse than your issue, I was unable to print at all,but:  only the "Green" LED basic power & "print mode" LED would blink using any way (icon or terminal).
This command identified my issue.

```
sudo hp-check -r
```

Never used distro you gave, but
Your terminal command may come in two steps:

```
$ su -
```

Puts you in "Super User" mode with your password.
Then,

```
$ hp-check-r
```

This indicated 2 problems: Found CUPS not configured properly & I had the wrong driver.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am new to Ubuntu too and was not aware of hp-check, which led me to looking at the CUPS error log, but I haven't been able to fix the problem yet.  I edited the post and added some info from the CUPS error log, maybe you could take a look.

Comment: Never mind, problem solved! Comments above.